# Change input border color in Ionic application with button click

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out, how to change input border color in Ionic TypeScript application with button click, if I have input `class="mess"` in html:

```
<form>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input class="mess"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

with default color in `.css`:

```
.mess {
  border: 2px solid #88ff00;
}
```

I can't find the way, how to change `border` color from `#88ff00;` to different color `#95214b;` with click:

```
 <ion-button (click)="changeBorderColor()">Change color</ion-button>
```

I've tried use `document.documentElement.style.setProperty` in `changeBorderColor()` function, but looks like I've to use some different way for result.

Comment: try `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way...

> page.html file

```
  <form>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input  [ngClass]="setBorderColor? 'mess'  : ''"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-button (click)="changeBorderColor()">Change color</ion-button>
  </form>
```

> page.ts file

```
 public setBorderColor: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeBorderColor() {
    this.setBorderColor = true;
  }
```

> page.scss file

```
.mess {
  border: 2px solid #88ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```node
<ion-button (click)="changeBorderColor()">Change color</ion-button>

<script>

function changeBorderColor(){
 
   document.getElementById(".mess").style.borderColor = "#95214b";

}
```

Next to your `class="mess"` add an `id="mess"` and in the script where it says `getElementById="#mess"` or you can use `getElementByClassName=".mess"` either should work fine.